# Accessing the Most Recently Taken Photo in Android Phone then Displaying it with ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, photo

I'm trying to sort the images in MediaStore by date taken, and then displaying it through ImageView. However, nothing appears on the screen when I test the app. Everything is imported, and all the permissions were requested.

I have tried changing the xml to see if the layer had been hidden, but the test image take straight from drawables appeared when I tested.

```
private lateinit var newImageView: ImageView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3)

        newImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)

        val contentResolver: ContentResolver = contentResolver
        val imageUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID)
        val sortOrder = "${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN} DESC"
        val cursor = contentResolver.query(imageUri, projection, null, null, sortOrder)

        var recentImageUri: String? = null

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val imageId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID))
            recentImageUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageId).toString()
            cursor.close()
        }

        if (recentImageUri != null) {
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(recentImageUri)
            newImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
```

Comment: Could you please add code snippet to your question that what you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I just added the code. I forgot to paste it in when I was posting.